# How to refer resources in cloudformation created in it

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I would like to create an monitoring instance with rights to terminate, create, destroy instances, autoscaling groups, tags etc. within the scope of cloudformation it was created in.

What resource should I give to the policy to make it work ?

```
 {                                                                                         
            "PolicyName": "ManageCloudformationInstances",                                                         
            "PolicyDocument": {                                                                     
              "Statement": [                                                                        
                {                                                                                   
                  "Effect": "Allow",                                                                
                  "Action": [                                                                       
                    "ec2:*"                                          
                  ],                                                                                
                  "Resource": "?????"                                                                   
                }                                                                                   
              ]                                                                                     
            }                                                                                       
          },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I guess there are two part to your question.

If you are creating instance in your cloudformation template then you can easily just use the [GetAtt function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html) to pull the `Arn` for those resources.

However if you are trying to dynamically allow it to delete instances inside of an autoscaling group then you need dynamically edit your policy to allow that. The easiest way that comes to mind is to trigger a lambda function every time that your ASG scales and edit the policy to include the ARNs from the recent scaling activity.

You probably want to start with something like this for the ASG - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/cloud-watch-events.html

Comment: Hi! You answer is perfect. That I was looking for. The first would be the easiest, but I would like manage instances in autoscaling groups.

You are right I should use cloudwatch for this purpose rather managing these instances manually. I will look up at docs and combine setting instaces as unhealthy so the can be scaled down, which I wanted to achieve.